# Passing a number string to Capistrano converts the string to a float rather than preserving the string value

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I'm trying to pass a version number from the command line to my Capistrano cap deploy script. My version numbers aren't really numbers or floats, they are strings that I am passing in.

In my specific case, I'm deploying version 7.10 of my app, but when I pass that string into my cap command the Capfile automatically converts that to 7.1.  I actually have another script that actually invokes the cap command.  The cap command that gets executed is similar to:

```
cap -f /path/to/Capfile -S domain=dev.example.com -S ssh_port=22 -S mysql_pass= -S sitename=example.com -S dbname=example-com -S drupalversion="7.10" deploy
```

The problem is the drupalversion variable comes in to the Capfile ruby script as 7.1.  How can I preserve the string value of the value I'm passing in?

Comment: This is kind of a hack, but one thing I did to circumvent this is added a string character as the first character of the version number, and then pulled a substring of the value being passed in from the second character to the end of the string.

`set :drupal_version, drupalversion[1,5] if exists?(:drupalversion)`

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: escape the quotes on the command line.

```
drupalversion=\"7.10\"
```

The problem is that capistrano is coercing the variables into the appropriate strongly typed variables in ruby which probably desired in most cases. Here is the bit of code that performs the coercion.

```
def coerce_variable(value)
  case value
    when /^"(.*)"$/ then $1
    when /^'(.*)'$/ then $1
    when /^\d+$/ then value.to_i
    when /^\d+\.\d*$/ then value.to_f
    when "true" then true
    when "false" then false
    when "nil" then nil
    else value
  end
end
```

You can see that the regular expressions look for quotes in order to preserve the value as a string. However, the quotes aren't passed through from the command line, only the contents are. Escaping the quotes ensures that the they are passed in to ruby and then Capistrano can correctly coerce the variable as a string instead of a float.